# In the introduction to Perek Shirah, which animal eats the frog?

Tags: perek-shira

Please see the introduction to Perek Shirah [(PDF source)](http://zootorah.com/assets/media/perek-shirah-booklet.pdf#page=2).

In story of David hamelech who meets the frog, it says that the frog told him that he gives up his life as he allows himself to be eaten by a land creature that only feeds on animals from the sea.

What is this creature?

Comment: This question would be improved with your source for the story. Otherwise, it is hard to know what you are referring to.

Comment: https://www.breslev.co.il/articles/family/breslev_kids/king_david_and_the_frog.aspx?id=11643&language=english

Comment: Not only that, but I involve myself in a great mitzvah, and this is the mitzvah that I involve myself with: There's a specie on the beach whose sustenance comes exclusively from (creatures that live) in the water, and when it's hungry, it takes me and eats me. I therefore fulfill the mitzvah of that what is said (Proverbs 25:21-22), "If your adversary is hungry, feed him

Answer (score 1):

The source says it refers to a creature on the edge of the sea, but not necessarily a land creature. In Nature's Song (the source of your PDF), Rabbi Slifkin understands it to be a water creature. He says many animals eat frogs, including heron, otters, and snakes. Personally I think otters or sea turtles are very likely.